# Difference between use ''#text'' and InnerText XML (Powershell)

Tags: xml, powershell, scheduled-tasks, innertext

I am working on updating some values inside an XML file and I am doing this using PowerShell.
The XML file is an exported Scheduled Task definition and I am trying to update the value of the Command node, I want to change some part of the path to the program to execute and I am using this code:

```
 1-|[xml]$taskXmlDefinition = Get-Content -Path $pathXmlTaskDefinition
 2-|$oldCommand = $taskXmlDefinition.Task.Actions.Exec.Command
 3-|$programName = Split-Path -Leaf -Path $oldCommand
 4-|$newCommand =  Join-Path $newPath $programName
 5-|$taskXmlDefinition.GetElementsByTagName("Command")[0].'#text' = $newCommand
 6-|$newTaskXmlFilepath = (Join-Path $newPath $name)
 7-|$taskXmlDefinition.Save($newTaskXmlFilepath)
```

With that code, I am getting this error:
[image]

The error is fixed if I change the line 5 for either one of this two:

```
 5-|$taskXmlDefinition.GetElementsByTagName("Command")[0].'#text' = $newCommand.ToString()
```

or

```
 5-|[string]($taskXmlDefinition.GetElementsByTagName("Command")[0].'#text') = $newCommand
```

But, I know that if I ask `($newCommand).GetType()` The result will be `System.String` and there shouldn't be need to add `.ToString()`

I changed the line (5) for this code:

```
5-|$taskXmlDefinition.GetElementsByTagName("Command")[0].InnerText = $newCommand
```

and it's working fine. I don't understand the difference or what is going on that I need to make the cast to string explicit.

Can someone explain me the difference in this cases?

Comment: Why don't you just access the command field like you did when you set the `$oldCommand` variable?

Comment: I am open to any suggestion about the code, but my question is what is the problem with the original code, why in the way that I had the first time doesn't work? The three lines that I added at the end of the question make the code works fine, but I will still have the same problem, that I don't understand what is the difference between the lines of code.

Comment: What does `($taskXmlDefinition.GetElementsByTagName("Command")[0].'#text').GetType()` return?

Comment: ($taskXmlDefinition.GetElementsByTagName("Command")[0].'#text').GetType()  (IsPublic -> True | IsSerial ->True | Name-> String  | BaseType-> System.Object)

Comment: And if I do ($taskXmlDefinition.GetElementsByTagName("Command")[0].InnerText ).GetType() I get the same result (IsPublic -> True | IsSerial ->True | Name-> String | BaseType-> System.Object)

Comment: Perhaps, unless you specifically cast or declare a variable as a specific type, it defaults to System.Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be related to this bug in PowerShell: [XML nodes are too picky about setting values](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2459).

Workaround (incomplete, choose any):

```
$taskXmlDefinition.GetElementsByTagName("Command")[0].'#text' = "$newCommand"
$taskXmlDefinition.GetElementsByTagName("Command")[0].'#text' = $newCommand.ToString()
$taskXmlDefinition.GetElementsByTagName("Command")[0].'#text' = [string]$newCommand
$taskXmlDefinition.GetElementsByTagName("Command")[0].'#text' = $newCommand.PSObject.BaseObject
```

or apply any of above *cast-like* operations to `$newCommand` assignment e.g. as follows:

```
$newCommand =  (Join-Path $newPath $programName).ToString()
$taskXmlDefinition.GetElementsByTagName("Command")[0].'#text' = $newCommand
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought it was a PowerShell but I wasn't sure. Interesting situation, it's very useful to know that.